# Framework not found AssetsLibrary in xcode 4.5

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4.5, assetslibrary

I am using Xcode 4.5 for developing iPhone application.I need to add 'AssetsLibrary.framework' into my project.But I can't see the framework in 'build phases' of my target.Please go through the following image then you can easily understand my issue.Please help me..
[image]

Comment: did you delete Asset Library? check your trash. It should be under adSupport framework. If you did not find in trash you have to install the ios 6 sdk or try to re install xcode 4.5.

Answer (score 2):

check wheather it is present or not  at below path

/System/Library/Frameworks/AssetsLibrary.framework

if it is not available at above path then this framewok is deleted by you accidently or may be purposely by someone else

and you have to reinstall the SDK